# Get model object from ImageTarget Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Currently, i'm trying to work with augment reality in android. For this task i'm using `Unity` + `Vuforia`.

So, i have made a scene, which is working, when i'm looking to specific object from my camera it shows me my model(basically 3d cat model with animation). I've done this according to tutorials like this:
[text format tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-augmented-reality-camera-sensor-setup--mobile-7873) and videos on youtube like this : [video tutroial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvSrZqP0elQ).

After this i've made android application, based on this `scene`, like this:
[image]

The result is Android project, which basically has one `Activity` and banch of `assets` and `libs`. The only connection with `Unity` that i see so far is `UnityPlayer` class, but it's just a `ViewGroup`, extended from `FrameLayout`

```
public class UnityPlayer extends FrameLayout implements com.unity3d.player.a.a
```

**My goal:** I need to override`onClick` on the view from `Unity`, which i've created(my 3d cat), something like when you click on cat on your phone, it will make some sound, and set some animation to it on after clicking. I have a model on the `scene`, just logically it has been converted to `View` class inside of `Android`, and i thought that it's just a child of `UnityPlayer`, but code like this :

```
mUnityPlayer.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener
```

has no effect.

**I want either have some object which will contain all the animations and other properties which model in unity has, or if it's impossible, learn how to set onClick listeners in Unity itself**

***I realize that this question might be unclear, and i would like to explain it in more details for those who would try to help.***

If you need more info, just ask for it in comments. Thanks

**Edit:** As answer was suggesting, i could simply write a script for this, which i did, for using `VirtualButton`, it looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Vuforia;

    public class VirtualButtonEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler {

        // Private fields to store the models
        private GameObject kitten;
        private GameObject btn;
        /// Called when the scene is loaded
        void Start() {

            // Search for all Children from this ImageTarget with type VirtualButtonBehaviour
            VirtualButtonBehaviour[] vbs = GetComponentsInChildren<VirtualButtonBehaviour>();
            for (int i = 0; i < vbs.Length; ++i) {
                // Register with the virtual buttons TrackableBehaviour
                vbs[i].RegisterEventHandler(this);
            }

            // Find the models based on the names in the Hierarchy
            kitten = transform.FindChild("kitten").gameObject;

            btn = transform.FindChild("btn").gameObject;

            kitten.SetActive(false);
            btn.SetActive(true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the virtual button has just been pressed:
        /// </summary>
        public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb) {
            //Debug.Log(vb.VirtualButtonName);
            //GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 10, 5), "Hello World!");


        }

        /// Called when the virtual button has just been released:
        public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb) { 

        }
    }
```

As you can see, in `Start()` method i want to find and hide model, which called `kitten`, but it's not hiding

*I've attached this script to virtual button object, i will provide a screen:*

[image]

**Edit:** My mistake actually, for some reason, i had to attach `VirtualButtonBehaviorHandler` script to an `ImageTarget`, it's not that simple to understand for me, but i think i see some logic behind it right now. 
***But, for some unknow reason, if i'm adding this code:***

```
public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb) {
        //Debug.Log(vb.VirtualButtonName);
        switch(vb.VirtualButtonName) {
        case "btn":
            kitten.setActive(true);
            break;
        }

    }
```

***It works instantly, even without touching on the button***

**Final edit:** This was happenning, because i've add my button in database `.xml`, when i've removed button from it - everything worked, i'm marking the only one answer as correct, because it helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brother Everything is possible if we do it. As per my understanding , what exactly you want to do is :

**First : You need to clear some basic concept by reading blog & Tutorials:**

1. As you mentioned object on which your white cyte :) cat render is "Marker"
2. In Unity Everything is gameobject you can write script to manipulate that gameobject (CAT) using script. which will be in either C#(Mono) or JavaScript for this work you can use Visual Studio or MonoDevelop by Unity
   But before that please search for keywords on google

   a)  **Touchevent, RayCastMenu Controle** in unity: To handle Touch

   b)  **MonoBehaviour** class, **Start()** , **Update()**, OnGUI() method in  Unity
3. You can identify any gameObject by using its **name or Tag** which you can see or change in **Inspector window**

These are some basic things . Please follow vuforia developer portal to learn more:
https://developer.vuforia.com/library/

---

**Now: Coming to your question:** 
According to me you wanna do some stuff on Click of your sweet cat . 
Its simple, if simply you want to launch android activity on click of cat then there are 2 possible ways:

1. Create android project and import it in unity as Library project in Unity.

   OR
2. create android activity from unity project with the help of C# script. Attach this script to any GameObject in scene.

**Here I providing the example of second one  :** On click of Button It will launch Android Activity.
What you have to do is:

Replace Button GameObject By CAT GameObjectExport Project as Android and write activity with same name and package as mention in C# code to do whatever you want to

**Here In my example I have explained:**

1. How to popup GUI when Marker is detected using Unity+ Vuforia
2. How to launch android Activity from Unity Code on Specific event
3. How to handle Event in Unity
4. How to maintain GUI same with multiple Resolutions

---

Please Study code Carefully and read the comments also :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Vuforia; //import Vuforia 
using System;

public class ButtonPopup : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler 

{

    float native_width= 1920f;// Native Resolution to maintain resolution on different screen size
    float native_height= 1080f;
    public Texture btntexture;// drag and drop any texture in inspector window

    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

    private bool mShowGUIButton = false;


    void Start () {


        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour) {
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
        }
    }

    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            mShowGUIButton = true;// Button Shown only when marker detected same as your cat
        }

        else
        {
            mShowGUIButton = false;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI() {

        //set up scaling
        float rx = Screen.width / native_width;
        float ry = Screen.height / native_height;

        GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS (new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, new Vector3 (rx, ry, 1));

        Rect mButtonRect = new Rect(1920-215,5,210,110);


        if (!btntexture) // This is the button that triggers AR and UI camera On/Off
        {
            Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture on the inspector");
            return;
        }

        if (mShowGUIButton) {

            // different screen position for your reference
            //GUI.Box (new Rect (0,0,100,50), "Top-left");
            //GUI.Box (new Rect (1920 - 100,0,100,50), "Top-right");
            //GUI.Box (new Rect (0,1080- 50,100,50), "Bottom-left");
            //GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 100,Screen.height - 50,100,50), "Bottom right");

            // draw the GUI button
            if (GUI.Button(mButtonRect, btntexture)) {
                // do something on button click 
                OpenVideoActivity();
            }
        }
    }

    public void OpenVideoActivity()
    {
        var androidJC = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer”);// any package name maintain same in android studio
        var jo = androidJC.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        // Accessing the class to call a static method on it
        var jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.mobiliya.gepoc.StartVideoActivity”);//Name of android activity
        // Calling a Call method to which the current activity is passed
        jc.CallStatic("Call", jo);
    }

}
```

Remember : In Unity everything is GameObject and you can write script to manipulate any GameObject

**Edit: Info for Virtual Button**

Virtual Buttons detect when underlying features of the target image are obscured from the camera view. You will need to place your button over an area of the image that is rich in features in order for it to reliably fire its OnButtonPressed event. To determine where these features are in your image, use the Show Features link for your image in the Target Manager.

Choose areas in the images that have dimensions of approximately 10% of the image target’s size.

---

Here is example in image i have simplify for you:

---

[image]

---

**Register the Virtual Button:**

To add a virtual button to an image target, add the VirtualButton element and its attributes to the ImageTarget element in the .xml file.

**XML Attributes:**

1. Name - a unique name for the button
2. Rectangle - defined by the four corners of the rectangle in the
   target's coordinate space
3. Enabled - a boolean indicating whether the button should be enabled
   by default
4. Sensitivity - HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW sensitivity to occlusion

---

**You can get .Xml file in streamingAsset folder in unity projec**t .

```
 <ImageTarget size="247 173" name="wood">
  <VirtualButton name="red" sensitivity="HIGH" rectangle="-108.68 -53.52 -75.75 -65.87"
   enabled="true" />
  <VirtualButton name="blue" sensitivity="LOW" rectangle="-45.28 -53.52 -12.35 -65.87"
   enabled="true" />
  <VirtualButton name="yellow" sensitivity="MEDIUM" rectangle="14.82 -53.52 47.75 -65.87"
   enabled="true" />
  <VirtualButton name="green" rectangle="76.57 -53.52 109.50 -65.87"
   enabled="true" />
</ImageTarget>
```

---

**After Registering Virtual Button Code is simple then:**

```
public class Custom_VirtualButton : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

// here it finds any VirtualButton Attached to the ImageTarget and register it's event handler and in the
//OnButtonPressed and OnButtonReleased methods you can handle different buttons Click state
//via "vb.VirtualButtonName" variable and do some really awesome stuff with it.
        VirtualButtonBehaviour[] vbs = GetComponentsInChildren<VirtualButtonBehaviour>();
        foreach (VirtualButtonBehaviour item in vbs)
        {
            item.RegisterEventHandler(this);
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }


    #region VirtualButton

    public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb)
    {
        Debug.Log("Helllllloooooooooo");
    }

    public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb)
    {
        Debug.Log("Goooooodbyeeee");
    }

    #endregion //VirtualButton
}
```

and after writing this code you have to go to StreamingAsset/QCAR and find your ImageTarget XML Association  & do  something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QCARConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="qcar_config.xsd">
  <Tracking>
    <ImageTarget name="marker01" size="100.000000 100.000000">

      <VirtualButton name="red" rectangle="-49.00 -9.80 -18.82 -40.07" enabled="true" />
    </ImageTarget>
  </Tracking>
</QCARConfig>
```

Best of Luck :) Bdw CAT is so cute:)

Comment: Yes, your answer is very helpful, as you mentioned, everything is a basically GameObject, and i've made a scprit for using virtual button, the only problem here, it is not working at all, i've made changes in my question, please look when you have some spare time

Comment: hi, please check the edited answer ,  and be free to ask if you have any difficulty again